# Is there a way to see or edit Reminder locations in iCal?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, ical, reminders

With iCloud it is possible to associate a location trigger with Reminders generated on an iOS 5 device, but there seems to be no way to view or edit these locations in iCal. Is that true?

*Is there a way to see or edit the locations associated with iCloud Reminders within iCal?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to see or edit the locations associated with iCloud Reminders within iCal?

In a word, "no".

Even in Mountain Lion Developer Preview with access to a standalone Reminders app (Reminders, or "todos" were removed from iCal - hooray!) there is no ability to see these from OS X.  Note, all this *could* change, ML is Beta after all.  But certainly in Lion and iCal, it's a straight no, and always will be.